# Is there any way to make the controls on an HTML5 video always show on IE?

Tags: html, html5-video

In IE, the controls hide away when the cursor is not on the video. Is there a way to keep it there always?

```
<video width="580" height="318" controls poster="link to poster" preload="none">
    <source src="video.mp4">
    <source src="video.ogv">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 Video tag. Please update to a <a href="https://www.google.com/chrome/" target="_blank">modern browser</a>.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Properly not.
Instead you can disable the standard controls and make your own.